# Isn't this an array reference? Why isn't it an array reference?

Tags: perl, oop, perl-data-structures

I'm trying to debug a puzzling problem with the following lines, deep in the guts of a program I've inherited,

```
my $log = [];
$root->validate_subtree($log);
```

results in the following error

> Treex::PML::Node::validate: log must be an ARRAY reference

`$root` is an object of type `Treex::PML::Node`, and and the two lines really are adjacent-- I haven't left anything out. I went to the source of the error message, and`validate_subtree()` checks its argument as follows (Node.pm line 423):

```
sub validate_subtree {
  my ($node, $log) = @_;
  if (defined $log and UNIVERSAL::isa($log,'ARRAY')) {
    croak __PACKAGE__."::validate: log must be an ARRAY reference";
  }
```

I thought that `$log = []` *does* initialize `$log` to an array reference! What am I missing?

Comment: @MarcB No, it's a reference. An array would be `@array`.

Comment: That would be `\()`, no? [Perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Making-References) says, and I quote: "A reference to an anonymous array can be created using square brackets: `$arrayref = [1, 2, ['a', 'b', 'c']];`"

Comment: @MarcB Would you please delete your comment. It's completely inaccurate and could potentially confuse people reading this page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct.  The code you've shown does set `$log` to an array reference.  This code:

```
sub validate_subtree {
  my ($node, $log) = @_;
  if (defined $log and UNIVERSAL::isa($log,'ARRAY')) {
    croak __PACKAGE__."::validate: log must be an ARRAY reference";
  }
```

croaks precisely when `$log` is in fact an array reference.  I would guess you've found a bug in the distribution, and it should be

```
  if (defined $log and not UNIVERSAL::isa($log,'ARRAY')) {
```

Comment: For real? I just assumed `isa($log, 'ARRAY')` is true only if I pass a real array, not a reference! But that could only be a `@variable`, couldn't it...

Comment: @alexis: `$log` is a scalar variable; it *cannot* be an array, only a reference to an array

Comment: or `if ( ! defined $log || ! UNIVERSAL::isa($log,'ARRAY') )`

Comment: @ysth: I think from the docs (https://metacpan.org/pod/Treex::PML::Node) that `$log` is an optional parameter.  So `undef` is fine but say `3` or `{}` is less so.

Comment: Yup, it's optional. That's why the error check only happens if it's defined.